# Big Query returns 0 rows using count(*)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to join 2 tables, display some info of the tables as well as the total number of matched items. Here's the standardSQL query I'm trying to run on Big Query:

```
SELECT "Active" AS type, COUNT(*) AS total, t2.display_name AS name
FROM `TABLE_1` t1
JOIN `TABLE_2` t2 ON t1.assigned_employee_id = t2.id
WHERE status = 0;
```

Running the above gives me this error:

`SELECT list expression references t2.display_name which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:69]`

So I group by the `display_name` as suggested in the error to get the following query:

```
SELECT "Active" AS type, COUNT(*) AS total, t2.display_name AS name
FROM `TABLE_1` t1
JOIN `TABLE_2` t2 ON t1.assigned_employee_id = t2.id
WHERE status = 0
GROUP BY t2.display_name
```

Running this gives me this output:
`Query returned zero records.`

But if there are no matched records, I want to still get a row returned with `total` set to 0. If I remove `t2.display_name AS name` column from the original query, I will get a row returned

```
 Row |  type  | total    
  1  | Active |   0
```

How can I get the same output, but with the addition of the `dispaly_name`?

Comment: What table is status in?  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: @alamoot - hi , I am very sorry, I was wrong about Tim's answer - it was correct - my bad. my answer still correct but I will remove it

Comment: You can keep it as an alternate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second query, move the logic in your `WHERE` clause into the count using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    "Active" AS type,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 END) AS total,
    t2.display_name AS name
FROM `TABLE_1` t1
JOIN `TABLE_2` t2
    ON t1.assigned_employee_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.display_name
```

One explanation for why you are getting no records is that you don't have any data with a zero status.  The `WHERE` clause would then be filtering off *all* records.  By using conditional aggregation, every group would be returned, with a count of zero, or possibly greater.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do this all in one line?

```
SELECT 'Active' AS type, COUNT(*) AS total,
        ARRAY_AGG(t2.display_name) AS names
FROM `TABLE_1` t1 JOIN
     `TABLE_2` t2
      ON t1.assigned_employee_id = t2.id
WHERE status = 0;
```

This will always return one row, with an array of the names you are looking for.

Comment: This will return empty `disaply_name` for me